# Design pattern for methods that return object and NRVO

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, nrvo

I have class:

```
class A{
public:
    A(int v){
        this->v=new int;
        *(this->v)=v;
    }
    ~A(){
        delete v;
    }
    A add(A &a, A  &b){
        A res(0);
        *(res.v)=*(a.v)+*(b.v)+*v;
        return res;
    }
    int get(){
        return *v;
    }
private:    
    A();
    int* v;    
    void operator=(const A &other);
    TreePointer(const A &other);
};
```

I want to use it as follows:

```
A finalRes=a.add(b,c).add(a,a);
```

It works perfectly, there is no any leaks memory. 
But how to implement a similar behavior and usage, without using NRVO optimization? What standard design patterns exist for this purpose?

Comment: Follow rule of 3/5/0.

Comment: "*It works perfectly, there is no any leaks memory.*" It most assuredly is faulty; your violation of the rule of 5 ensures that it will leak memory. Oh sure, copy elision may save you, but that's an *optimization*, not a requirement. It's still broken even if you managed to get away with it.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid `new`, prefer `std::unique_ptr` instead.

In your case, in fact, you don't even need pointer:

```
class A{
public:
    explicit A(int v) : v(v){}
    ~A() = default;
    void operator=(const A &) = default;
    A(const A &) = default;
    A add(const A& a, const A& b) const { return A{v + a.v + b.v}; }
    int get() const { return v; }
private:
    int v;
};
```